# How do I complete these strings

Tags: php, query-string

I am trying to create/complete URL paths.
I am given a bunch of sku numbers that need to be inserted into a url.

Example URL:

> http ://www.website.com/image/1111-large.jpg
>   
> http ://www.website.com/image/1112-large.jpg

Im guessing it would look something like this?

```
print("http://www.website.com/image/$sku-large.jpg")
```

Example of given Sku numbers:
**1111

1112

1113

1114**
I need to echo these strings out.

I am very very new to PHP. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried that? Did it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you are 99% of the way there.

```
$skus = array(1111,1112,1114,1115,11116);

foreach ($skus as $sku)
{
    echo "http://www.website.com/image/$sku-large.jpg\n";
}
```

Comment: the only problem with an array is the , that separates the values/sku's .. the sku's are given to me an a .csv file. How can I seperate the sku's?

Comment: Thank you.. Used:---> print nl2br ('http: //www.website.com/image/'.$sku.'-large.jpg'."\n"); WORKED LIKE A CHARM!

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote,

```
print("http://www.website.com/image/$sku-large.jpg");
```

should work. (Note the semicolon at the end of the line).

Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know where those "Sku numbers" are coming from, but this is how you add a variable to a string:

```
echo 'http://www.website.com/image/'.$sku.'-large.jpg';
```

I am using the concatenation operator (`.`) to append the variable to the string.

Comment: The sku's a listed in a .csv file

Comment: @Michael Zebold: You can use PHP's [`str_getcsv()`-function](http://php.net/str_getcsv) as of PHP 5.3.